# Push Notifications Delay on Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I used Google Calendar Push Notifications.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

Suddenly, the notification was delayed.
It usually arrives in 0.5 to 2 seconds. But In Delay, arrives in 5 minitues to 1 hour.

It seems to be doing a something check in Google Calendar API.

I want some hints... (Because Any Errors? Any Penalties? Any ...)

Comment: i noticed the same problem for a few days now. Not sure whats the cause

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on and off, anyone having any updates?

Comment: We've been seeing this now and then, as well :-(  No root cause yet.